# Calculating probability of rolling a die exact number of times in a

Tags: probability

I have a game that can be summarised by throwing 2 fifty side dice. One round of the game is finished when each die is rolled once. Each game lasts 8 rounds (16 dice rolls) unless 1s are thrown during any round. If on a single round either die is rolled to a 1 then the  number of rounds in a game is increased by 2 rounds. If both dice show a 1 then the number of rounds increase by 4. I need to be able to calculate the probability of the a game containing exactly n rounds.
Calculating 8 rounds is easy, just the probability of not throwing a 1 on both dice to the power of 8. But calculating the probability of going 20 rounds I'm struggling with.

Comment: Do the bonus rounds also trigger round extensions if a $1$ is rolled during them?

Comment: Yes that's correct,  I believe that's what's tripping me up

Comment: If I have understood properly (not clear) then, for sufficiently large $n$, in order to  get to round $n$ with no more rounds in reserve then:  $n$ must be even,  and you must have thrown exactly $\frac {n-8}2$ $1's$ in the first $n-2$ rounds and you can't have thrown a $1$ in the $(n-1)^{st}$ round.  That's just a simple binomial computation.

Comment: Ah, maybe not.  Taking $n=12$, say, then at some point I needed two $1's$ but it's no good if they both came in round $10$ since the game would have already ended after round $8$.   So my count is correct (I think) but I need the $1's$ to occur early enough...hard to work that in to the naive computation.

Comment: @lulu I have a difficult time parsing what you wrote, but the chance of rolling two 1's in a single round complicates matters a good bit.  Letting $o$ represent a round with no 1's rolled, $1$ a round where exactly one $1$ was rolled, $\star$ a round where two $1$'s are rolled and $|$ denoting where the game should have actually ended, check to make sure fringe cases like $oooooooo|\star ooo$ aren't accidentally being counted the same as $11oooooooooo|$

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem?  Are you expecting an exact solution, or a numerical one?

Comment: @JMoravitz  Well, as I said, I think that what I wrote was wrong so I'm not sure it's worth explaining it.  Still, I'm not sure why it matters if two $1's$ were thrown in the same round or in two different ones.  Trusting that they are thrown at all, then each $1$ gets you two more rounds.

Comment: The generating function $R(z)$ for the number of roll pairs required by a single round is $R(z) = z\left[2p(1-p)[R(z)]^2+p^2[R(z)]^4\right]$ for a probability $p$ of rolling a $1$ on a single die ($p = 1/50$ in the present problem).  This doesn't look pretty...

Comment: Thanks for everyone's reply. I am not sure how the above generating function guarantees 8 minimum rounds. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look for a pattern:

Probability to play exactly 8 rounds: 
$$\left(\dfrac{49}{50}\right)^{16}$$

Probability to play exactly 10 rounds:
$$\dbinom{16}{1}\left(\dfrac{49}{50}\right)^{19}\dfrac{1}{50}$$

Probability to play exactly 12 rounds:
$$\left(\dbinom{16}{2} + \dbinom{16}{1}\dbinom{2}{1}\right)\left(\dfrac{49}{50}\right)^{22}\left(\dfrac{1}{50}\right)^2 = \left[ \dbinom{16}{2}+2\dbinom{16}{1}\right]\left(\dfrac{49}{50}\right)^{22}\left(\dfrac{1}{50}\right)^2$$

Probability to play exactly 14 rounds:
$$\left(\dbinom{16}{3} + \dbinom{16}{2}\dbinom{4}{1} + \dbinom{16}{1}\left(\dbinom{2}{2} + \dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{2}{1} \right) \right)\left(\dfrac{49}{50} \right)^{25}\left(\dfrac{1}{50}\right)^3 = \left[ \dbinom{16}{3}+4\dbinom{16}{2}+5\dbinom{16}{1}\right]\left(\dfrac{49}{50} \right)^{25}\left(\dfrac{1}{50}\right)^3$$

Probability to play exactly 16 rounds:
$$\left[ \dbinom{16}{4} + \dbinom{16}{3}\dbinom{6}{1} + \dbinom{16}{2}\left(\dbinom{4}{2} + \dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{2}{1}\right)+\dbinom{16}{1}\left(\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{4}{1} + \dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{2}{2}+\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{2}{1}\right) \right]\left(\dfrac{49}{50}\right)^{28}\left(\dfrac{1}{50}\right)^4 = \left[\dbinom{16}{4}+6\dbinom{16}{3}+14\dbinom{16}{2}+14\dbinom{16}{1}\right]\left(\dfrac{49}{50}\right)^{28}\left(\dfrac{1}{50}\right)^4$$

Once you get past 40 games, this pattern changes a bit. But, it should help you figure out a formula for $8\le n \le 40$ and then $40 < n$.

Let $k = \dfrac{n-8}{2}$ be the number of 1s rolled. For $8\le n \le 40$, you have the coefficient of $\dbinom{16}{k}$ is 1 and the coefficient of $\dbinom{16}{k-1}$ is $2k$.

Then the coefficient of $\dbinom{16}{1}$ is the $k$-th Catalan number. In other words, it is $\dfrac{\dbinom{2k}{k}}{k+1}$

Similarly, you can probably find patterns for each coefficient.